# Show documents snapshot within a dynamic timeframe with Firestore

Tags: node.js, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on an app that dispatches vehicles to transport passengers from one point to another. I have a requirement to show a list of trips taking place from "now" and up to 24 hours ahead which are not completed.

So, I ended up doing is this straightforward code:

```
const pageSize = 50;
const now = moment.utc('09/24/2021 00:00');
const next24hs = now.clone().add(24, 'hour');

var query = firebase.firestore()
  .collection('reservations')
  .where('pickupDate', '>', now.toDate())
  .where('pickupDate', '<=', next24hs.toDate())
  .where('status', '!=', 'COMPLETED')
  .limit(pageSize)
  .orderBy('pickupDate', 'asc');

query.onSnapshot(spanpshot => {
  // add items into the list.
});
```

But if I leave the list open for 2 hours those conditions would still be the same ("from now to next24hs"), so I'll never see the trips with pickupDate of "09/25/2021 01:00". And if I leave the list open for 24hs (eventually all trips will be COMPLETED), then the list will show no trips.

Is there a way to do this with Firestore? Like a "dynamic condition" to see through the timeframe?

If that's not possible (apparently not, so far in my research), what do you think I should do to accomplish this? I'm using Firestore, Cloud Functions and VueJS.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

After understanding your problem better, I think what you're trying to achieve is to have your query update relative to the time. You essentially want a creeping timeframe. If you open your browser and left it running for 24 hours it would constantly update from the current time to 24 hours ahead.

This solution doesn't factor in VueJS and there would be a cleaner way to achieve it but it should give you an idea...

```js
let results = [];
const pageSize = 50;

setInterval(function(){ 

    // whatever gets the time now 
    const now = moment.utc(); 
    
    // https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/
    const next24hs = now.add(1, 'days');
    
    // Do query with new `now` and new `next24hs`
    var query = firebase.firestore()
        .collection('reservations')
        .where('pickupDate', '>', now.toDate())
        .where('pickupDate', '<=', next24hs.toDate())
        .where('status', '!=', 'COMPLETED')
        .limit(pageSize)
        .orderBy('pickupDate', 'asc');

    query.onSnapshot(snapshot => {
        // add items into the list.
    });

},600000); // every 10 minutes
```

If using VueJS you could combine this with `watcher` and `compute` to get a neater bit of code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm already doing onSnapshot after that (just edited the question). But my problem persists: If I leave the browser open, trips of "09/25/2021 01:00" don't fall into the conditions made in my query.

Comment: Ah I understand now, okay so the dates are static currently, s why not every 5 minutes retrigger the query with new timestamps and repopulate the list. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @JuanManuelGonzalezAlama updated with a new idea. It's not using VueJS but you can get the idea. Every 10 minutes the block will rerun. The dates will be recalculated, and the query will be updated fetching a new set of data that matches the criteria. Make sure to update the list entirely and not append.